# Displaying Unicode characters above U+FFFF on Windows

Tags: unicode, windows-xp, utf-16, astral-plane

the application I'm developing with EVC++ 4 runs on Windows CE 5 and should support unicode (AFAIK wchar_t uses UTF-16 on windows, so I'm using that), so I want to be able to test it with "more exotic" characters. Especially with characters that use 4 Byte in UTF-16 and not just 2. Therefore I'm trying to display such characters in a texteditor (atm on my desktop PC with Windows XP, not on the embedded device).

But I haven't managed it to do so yet. As an example I've chosen [this character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10800/index.htm).
Like mentioned [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10800/fontsupport.htm) "MPH 2B Damase" should support this character. So I downloaded the font and put it into Windows\Fonts. I created a textfile using a hexeditor (just to be sure) with following content:

```
FFFE D802 DC00
```

When I open it with notepad (which should be unicode-capable, right?) and use the downloaded font it doesn't display 1 char, as intended, but this 2:

```
˘Ü
```

What am I doing wrong? :)

Thanks!

hrniels

**Edit:**
Flipping the BOM, as suggested, doesn't work. Notepad (and all other editors I tried, too) displays two squares in this case. Interesting is that if I copy the two squares here (with firefox) I see the right character:

I've also tried it with Komodo Edit with the same result.

Using UTF-8 doesn't help notepad either.

Answer (score 1):

Your text editor might not like UTF-16. It probably assumes ANSI or UTF-8.

Try typing in the UTF-8 equivalent instead:

```
0xF0 0x90 0xA0 0x80
```

This won't help your testing, but will make sure your font isn't at fault. A text editor that does support UTF-16 is [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/).

Comment: 0xFFFE is the Byte-order mark, which indicates the use of UTF-16 (Little endian). Notepad should be able to detect this.

Comment: I am well aware of that. But he doesn't say if he is using Notepad or not. There are many text editors which don't handle UTF-16.

Comment: I've used notepad for the test. But I'll try that tomorrow, too.

Comment: I've tried it with Komodo Edit, but without success. Komodo displays the same as notepad :/

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you put the byte order mark the other way around?

*FEFF* D802 DC00

(At the moment the byte sequence is being interpreted as the two characters U+02D8 U+00DC, so hopefully flipping the BOM will cause the bytes to be read in the intended order)

Comment: Ah, maybe you're right. I'll try that tomorrow and report here :)

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work. If I change the BOM notepad (and all other editors I tried, too) displays two squares. Interesting is that if I copy the two squares here (with firefox) I see the right character: <pre></pre>

Comment: If it was one square, I'd have guessed that Notepad didn't have access to the font, but the fact that it displays two squares is a bad sign. It is interesting that the characters are preserved through cut/paste.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to read the [`_wfopen()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb(VS.80).aspx) documentation. There they specify the encoding parameter. BTW, I assumed you are already using Unicode (wchars).

I would recommend you to use UTF-8 in files with or without BOM but forcing your fopen to use UTF-8 flag. It looks `_wfopen("newfile.txt", "r, ccs=UTF-8");` will work with UTF-8 with or without BOM and also with UTF-16. Do not make the mistake of using the `ccs=Unicode`, it is a common thing to have UTF-8 files without BOM.

You should really read a little bit about Unicode before trying to work. This about this as a very good investment - it will save you time if you understand how Unicode works.

Here is a start http://blog.i18n.ro/newbie-guide-to-unicode/ and do not forget to read the links from the end of the article.

If you really need a simple text editor that allows you to play with Unicode encodings, use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and forget about Notepad.